# sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: MOLECULE

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to make a column in sqlite database table, in which i can write both fractional and text values.

```
c.execute("CREATE table MOLECULE(MOLECULE NUMBER INT, MOLECULE NAME TEXT, 'MOLECULAR FORMULA' TEXT )");

c.execute("INSERT INTO MOLECULE VALUES (1, 'WATER', 'H20')");

c.execute("INSERT INTO MOLECULE VALUES (2, 'X', ' BaFe0.5Nb0.5O3')");

conn.commit()
```

I am trying using string it gives me error: `sqlite3.Operational Error: duplicate column name: MOLECULE`

Comment: Check your table for existance.

Comment: now it has created the table but dont know how to see the table?

Comment: What do you mean by seeing? Go to your database client and list all tables, or make query.

Comment: Its solved now.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement appears to be the problem.  You don't need to repeat the table name when defining columns.  Try using this:

```
c.execute("CREATE table MOLECULE (NUMBER INT, NAME TEXT, \"MOLECULAR FORMULA\" TEXT)");
```

I have also replaced the single quotes you had around the `MOLECULAR FORMULA` column with escaped double quotes.  Double quotes are the standard way to escape names in SQLite.  If that doesn't work, you could try just using underscore as a separator, e.g. `MOLECULAR_FORMULA`, which would not require any escaping.

Comment: It has created table molecule, how can i see the table?

Comment: If there is no data in the table, then there is nothing to see.  Try doing `SELECT * FROM MOLECULE` ... but again, it would probably be empty unless you have inserted data.

Comment: for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM MOLECULE");
print row                                                                                                               syntex error here.

Comment: I have answered your original question.  If you need help querying a raw SQLite table, or doing it through Python, then maybe you should ask another question.